# Is there an alternative to the Spark Cassandra connector?

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

My question is simple actually. Can we read/write data with Spark from/to Cassandra database without using the Spark-Cassandra-Connector? Is there also something else we could use? If so, is there any performance comparison between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Spark Cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) from DataStax is the only one I'm aware of.

There may be other proprietary connectors/drivers (likely paid versions) but I'm not familiar with them because all the enterprises I've worked with use the spark-cassandra-connector. Cheers!